# Symbolic functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative

I'm sorry if I'm not formerly correct; I would like to work with symbolic functions, like i.e. `x(t)` without the need to actually define `x`.

This may be useful because sometimes you'll have functions of `x`, and you want to calculate the derivative in `t`. For example

```
y(x) = y(x(t)) = t*x(t)

d y(x)             d x(t)
------  = x(t)+ t* ------
 d t                dt
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is pretty easy (after I spent 20 minutes making it very hard).

```
>> y = sym('t*x(t)')
>> y_dot = diff(y,t)
y_dot =
t*diff(x(t), t) + x(t)
```

You can also define some intermediates if you want

```
>> f = sym('x(t)');
>> y = t*f;
>> diff(y,'t')
ans =
t*diff(x(t), t) + x(t)
```

---

I also discovered the `mupad` command, which is worth trying out.  Within the mupad window, type `y(x) := t*x(t)`  and `diff(y(x),t)`.

Answer (score 1):

is that ok?
http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/symbolic_math.html